# Can clock() become slower inside a while loop?

Tags: c, time, embedded-linux, clock, beagleboneblack

I'm implementing a request-reply function on the BeagleBone Black for the UART. The function has to have a timeout measured in milliseconds. In order to measure the elapsed time I used the `clock()` function:

> The value returned is the CPU time used so far as a *clock_t*; to get the number of seconds used, divide by CLOCKS_PER_SEC

But the intended timeout behaviour didn't work so I started testing and I observed something really strange..

In main() before calling the actual req-rep function I turned to the `time()` function to check how big `clock()` becomes second by second:

```
time_t start;
uint32_t prev=0;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    prev = now;
    now = clock();
    printf("%2d. second: clock()=%10lu   delta:%10lu\n", i, now, now - prev);
    start = time(NULL);
    while (time(NULL) - start < 1){};
}
```

Results:

```
0. second: clock()=     10681   delta:     10681
1. second: clock()=    217461   delta:    206780
2. second: clock()=   1215264   delta:    997803
3. second: clock()=   2211733   delta:    996469
4. second: clock()=   3204658   delta:    992925
5. second: clock()=   4201332   delta:    996674
```

The delta values seem to be close enough to my expectations and also to my needs. But when I inserted a similar test code into the actual read function (called by the req-rep function)...

```
uint8_t uart_read(uint8_t port, void * dest, size_t req_size, size_t * recv_size, uint32_t timeout_ms){

    ssize_t    _recv        = 0;
    clock_t    _limit       = timeout_ms * (CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000);
    clock_t    _start       = clock();
    clock_t    prev         = 0;
    clock_t    now          = 0;
    uint8_t    i            = 0;
    time_t     start;

    if (! recv_size) return UART_ERROR;
    *recv_size = 0;

    while(1) {
        _recv = read(uart_fds[port], ((uint8_t*)dest) + (*recv_size), req_size - *recv_size);

        if (_recv < 0)                                          return UART_ERROR;   //error in read() function
        *recv_size += _recv;
        if (*recv_size == req_size)                             return UART_OK;      //reading finished completely
        if ((timeout_ms > 0) && ((clock() - _start) > _limit))  return UART_TIMEOUT; //reading timed out
        if (uart_ctokens[port] != 0)                            return UART_CANCEL;  //readig was cancelled by cancel token before reaching required read size

        prev = now;
        now = clock();
        printf("%2d. second: clock()= %10lu   delta:%10lu\n", i++, now, now - prev);
        start = time(NULL);
        while (time(NULL) - start < 1){};
    }
}
```

...it resulted completely different delta values which are far away from 1M:

```
0. second: clock()=    5877113   delta:   5877113
1. second: clock()=    6346335   delta:    469222
2. second: clock()=    6823636   delta:    477301
3. second: clock()=    7308902   delta:    485266
4. second: clock()=    7802444   delta:    493542
5. second: clock()=    8271812   delta:    469368
6. second: clock()=    8749332   delta:    477520
...
```

It seems that time goes half as quick inside the while loop than outside of it :)

In both cases when compared to the ticking of a phisical wall-clock the output lines appeared one second apart from each other.

Why are the delta values in the while loop less than half of the ones in the for loop in main()? How could I properly measure elapsed milliseconds in my read function?

Comment: `clock()` returns the amount of _CPU time *used*_, not wall-clock time! While `read()`'ing, you're not using the CPU, so it's not counted.

Comment: The turn-around time of your loop not only includes the delay by `time()` but also every other instruction therein. Move `start = time(NULL);` to the beginning of your loop.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist What is being used while `read()`'ing if not the CPU? This sounds weird. Could you explain a little more pls?

Comment: The `read()` system call is not something you, the user, can implement. It is a formal request from the user to the system to perform something on its behalf, during which the code will remain blocked. Because `read()` can take arbitrarily long, the program is considered in “(disk) sleep”, not running, and the OS could run another program instead. Meanwhile, the UART hardware buffers received bytes and interrupts periodically the OS. Yes that processing takes CPU time but it’s not continuously polling the UART and this CPU time is credited to the OS, not the user.